Body Margin not working On Wordpress CSS theme
I have this wordpress theme, the margin body or wrapper are not working, I tried all the body margin, wrapper margin, avoided most of the possible conflicts. but I still see in my browser a conflict between the main.css which is my style, and the browser css.
No margins show in mobile nor desktop mode.
It's a theme in wordpress. I tried some stuff with chatGpt but all in vain,
.wp-site-blocks {

  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  color: #000000ff;
  background-color: #FEFEFEff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}



.wp-elements-1c2ee1c28516952df80b30df07526130 a:where(:not(.wp-element-button)) {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

body>div.wp-site-blocks>div>div>footer>div ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 30px;

}

body>div.wp-site-blocks>div>div>footer>div p {
  margin-left: 39px;
}

body>div.wp-site-blocks>div>div>footer>div ul li {
  list-style: none;
}


body>div.wp-site-blocks>div>div>footer>div ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(235, 42, 42);
}

.wp-site-blocks p {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
}


.query-works h1,
.query-works h2 {

  color: black;

}



.wp-site-blocks h1,
.wp-site-blocks h2,
.wp-site-blocks h3 {
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 2em;
}



.wp-site-blocks h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
}


#modal-1-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


#modal-1-content>ul {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;

}

#modal-1-content>ul>li {

  width: 140px;
  justify-content: center;

}


#modal-1-content>ul>li>a {

  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;

}

#modal-1-content>ul>li>a:hover {

  color: #ff2d2c;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset;
}

.wp-site-blocks figure>img {

  width: 50rem;
  height: auto;
}






.main-nav {
  padding: 20px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

}


.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff2d2c;

}

.site-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

wp-site-blocks .site-title {
  color: black;
}

.query-posts a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;
}

.wp-block-social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.wp-block-social-links li {
  display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;

}

.wp-block-social-links li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;

}

